# Como creo un pop-up de politica de cookies

Tags: magnific-popup

Quiero crear un pop-up de politica de cookies para que se abra en el momento en que se finalice la carga de mi web.Con algun boton de aceptar,cacelar,leer.Alguien me puede indicar donde encontrar algunos ejemplos.
Lo siento soy muy novato a la hora de pedir informacion.

Comment: Hola AFAC4D, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una